# limitations on WSL 2 when compared to actual linux

Tags: linux, fork, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A couple of months ago windows [announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/)  Windows Subsystem for Linux 2, which features a linux kernal.

What limitations will still be present when compared to linux or other unix based OS's?

Does that mean that you will be able to fork processes using the subsystem?